# email isn't supported in region

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I followed the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html). Created the properties file but getting the error when attempting to send the mail using java sdk. I'm able to send the test mails using AWS web SES console.

Used **US West (Oregon)** and have production access for the region. Getting error

> Error message: email isn't supported in region us-west-2

Comment: Check to make sure you have all the parameters set correctly and that the production access is granted to the email address you are using in your Java code.  I tried to get access to SES, but they said they were worried about spam and never said why!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully sent emails using SES from a mulitiude of sources in us-west-2 including the web console, the CLI, and the ruby SDK.

Here are some tips I can offer for troubleshooting:

- Make sure that your SES is set to production so that you can send emails
- make sure you have a verified email address to both send from and send to
- check your instance roles permissions in IAM to be sure that the instance you are trying to send the email has the permission to do so
- test sending your email with just the CLI, this will help you troubleshoot the issue faster.

If all else fails set your endpoint / region to something else like us-east-1 and see if you still get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to download the latest version of the SDK from Maven.  They appear to hardcode supported services to regions within the library, so grabbing latest is what resolved it for me.